# How to prevent MacOs from switching keyboard input method

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina

I installed a perfectly fine and working custom layout and it works for everything I use. It is one of the Dvorak flavors if you’re curious.

The issue is that each time I open the App Store, it switches back to the default one. And I’m virtually unable to use it efficiently as I have to look at my keyboard to find keys. Same issue occurs on the login screen, I’m forced to use the default one and struggle to type my complicated password, for which I have perfect muscle memory in Dvorak. I use same keyboard layout on my Windows 10 computers and there it’s possible to have it as default.

I’m using Catalina 10.15.6

[image]

What can I do to end this annoyance?

Comment: You should be able to to switch to your custom layout in the login screen by just activating the input menu there.  This is done by checking a box in system prefs/users and groups/login options.

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to make this a comment, but what happens if you remove the ABC layout from the options there? (click on "ABC" and then click on the minus button)

Comment: It works until I reboot (also in order to remove it, the custom layout has to be installed in system /Library, which I did).
After reboot, the login is still in Qwerty and then I have to add the default one and remove it again in order to make the custom one work correctly again.